# int** vs int[const][const] differences

Tags: c, multidimensional-array

I was writing a code the other day and I found it rather strange, that int** and int[][] does not behave the same way. Can anyone point out the differences between them? Below is my sample code, which fails with a segmentation fault, if I pass constant size 2d array, while it does work fine when I pass a dinamically allocated 2d array.

I am confused mainly because ant int[] array works the same as int*.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void sort_by_first_row(int **t, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;


    for(i = m-1 ; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < i; ++j)
        {

            if(t[0][j] < t[0][j+1])
            {
                int k;  
                for(k = 0 ; k < n ;++k)
                {
                    int swap;
                    swap = t[k][j];
                    t[k][j] = t[k][j+1];
                    t[k][j+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    /* Working version */   
    /*int **t;

    t =(int**) malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i  < 3; ++i)
    {
        t[i] = (int*) malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    }*/

    /*WRONG*/
    int t[3][6];

    t[0][0] = 121;
    t[0][1] = 85;
    t[0][2] = 54;
    t[0][3] = 89;
    t[0][4] = 879;
    t[0][5] = 11;

    for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
        t[1][i] = i+1;

    t[2][0] = 2;
    t[2][1] = 4;
    t[2][2] = 5;
    t[2][3] = 3;
    t[2][4] = 1;    
    t[2][5] = 6;                

    sort_by_first_row(t, 3, 6);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So based on the below answers I realize, that a multidimensional array is stored continuously in a row major order. After some modification, the below code works:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void sort_by_first_row(int *t, int n, int m)
{
    int i, j;


    for(i = m-1 ; i > 0 ; --i)
    {
        for(j = 0 ; j < i; ++j)
        {

            if(t[j] < t[j+1])
            {
                int k;  
                for(k = 0 ; k < n ;++k)
                {
                    int swap;
                    swap = t[k*m + j];
                    t[k*m + j] = t[k*m + j+1];
                    t[k*m + j+1] = swap;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    int i, j;
    /* Working version */   
    /*int **t;

    t =(int**) malloc(3*sizeof(int*));
    for(i = 0; i  < 3; ++i)
    {
        t[i] = (int*) malloc(6*sizeof(int));
    }*/

    /*WRONG*/
    int t[3][6];

    t[0][0] = 121;
    t[0][1] = 85;
    t[0][2] = 54;
    t[0][3] = 89;
    t[0][4] = 879;
    t[0][5] = 11;

    for( i = 0; i < 6; ++i )
        t[1][i] = i+1;

    t[2][0] = 2;
    t[2][1] = 4;
    t[2][2] = 5;
    t[2][3] = 3;
    t[2][4] = 1;    
    t[2][5] = 6;                

    sort_by_first_row(t, 3, 6);

    for(i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < 6; ++j)
            printf("%d ", t[i][j]);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**My new question is this: How to modify the code, so that the procedure works with int[][] and int**** **also?**

Comment: What compiler do you use? This doesn't compile neither with Visual Studio neither with gcc: `cannot convert ‘int (*)[6]’ to ‘int**’`

Comment: There are dozens of questions here in SO about differences between pointers and arrays. Just pick one (or pick a good book).

Comment: It does compile with gcc 4.8.1 with the following warning: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘sort_by_first_row’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default]
  sort_by_first_row(t, 3, 6);
and note: 
note: expected ‘int **’ but argument is of type ‘int (*)[6]’
 void sort_by_first_row(int *t[6], int n, int m)

Comment: Pointers are not arrays. Arrays are not pointers. Section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/) explains the relationship.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int t[3][6]` is very nearly the same thing as `int t[18]`.  A single contiguous block of 18 integers is allocated in both cases.  The variable `t` provides the address of the start of this block of integers, just like the one-dimensional case.

Contrast this with the case you have marked as "working", where `t` gives you the address of a block of 3 pointers, each of which points to a block of memory with 6 integers.  It's a totally different animal.

The difference between `t[3][6]` and `t[18]` is that the compiler remembers the size of each dimension of the array, and automatically converts 2D indices into 1D offsets.  For example, the compiler automatically converts `t[1][2]` into `*(t + 1*6 + 2)` (equivalent to `t[8]` if it were declared as a one-dimensional array).

When you pass a multi-dimensional array to a function, there are two ways to handle it.  The first is to declare the function argument as an array with known dimension sizes.  The second is to treat your array like a 1D array.

If you are going to declare the size of your array, you would declare your function like this:

```
void sort_by_first_row(int t[][6], int n)
```

or this

```
void sort_by_first_row(int t[3][6])
```

You either have to declare all array dimension sizes, or you can leave out the first size.  In both cases, you access elements of `t` using `t[i][j]`; you've given the compiler enough information to do the offset math that converts from 2D notation to a 1D index offset.

If you treat it as a 1D array, you have to pass the array dimensions and then do the offset math yourself.

Here's a full working example, where `f` and `f2` both generate the same output:

```
void f(int* t, int m, int n)
{
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < n; j++)
        std::cout << t[i * n + j] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
}

void f2(int t[][6], int m)
{
for (int i = 0; i < m; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
        std::cout << t[i][j] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{
int t[3][6];
int val = 1;
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
    {
        t[i][j] = val;
        val++;
    }
}

f(&(t[0][0]), 3, 6);
f2(t, 3);

return 0;
}
```

One thing to note is the hack-ish way I had to pass `t` to `f`.  It's been a while since I wrote in C/C++, but I remember being able to pass `t` directly.  Maybe somebody can fill me in on why my current compiler won't let me.

Answer (score 3):

int** is quite different from int[][].  int** is simply a pointer to a pointer and would appear like the following:

[image]

in reality, you can access the entire multidimensional array with simply int* pointing to the first element, and doing simple math from that.

Here is the result of the separate allocations (in your commented code):

[image]

However when you allocate a multidimensional array, all of the memory is contiguous, and therefore easy to do simple math to reach the desired element.

```
int t[3][6];
int *t = (int*) malloc((3 * 6) * sizeof(int));  // <-- similarly
```

This will result in a contiguous chunk of memory for all elements.

You certainly can use the separate allocations, however you will need to walk the memory differently.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I do know, that int** is a pointer to an array of int*s where each int* is a pointer to an array of ints. However you dont specify, that how does int[][] stored in the memory. What is the difference?

Comment: int ** is not necessarily a pointer to an array.  It is just a pointer to a pointer to an int.  And what is beyond that int is up to you.

Comment: The drawing is really nice, thank you, though there is a slight mistake/absence. You left out t. T is pointing to the array of int pointers, hence the int** type and the int** cast. There is nothing wrong with that cast.

Comment: That is a fair statement.  I made a couple of corrections above.  My point was that you can cast that to whatever you like, and technically you had a pointer to an int pointer.  So you could iterate the 3 int pointers which were allocated.  But a single int pointer would also be sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Realize that `int **t` makes `t` a pointer to a pointer, while `int t[3][6]` makes `t` an array of an array. In most cases, when an array is used in an expression, it will become the value of the address of its first member. So, for `int t[3][6]`, when `t` is passed to a function, the function will actually be getting the value of `&t[0]`, which has type pointer to an array (in this case, `int (*)[6]`).

The type of what is being pointed at is important for how the pointer behaves when indexed. When a pointer to an object is incremented by 5, it points to the 5th object following the current object. Thus, for `int **t`, `t + 5` will point to the 5th pointer, while for `int (*t)[M]`, t + 5 will point to the 5th array. That is, the result of `t + 5` is the same as the result of `&t[5]`.

In your case, you have implemented `void sort_by_first_row(int **t, int n, int m)`, but you are passing it an incompatible pointer. That is, the type of `&t[0]` (which is what `t` will become in `main`) is not the same as what the function wants, a `int **t`. Thus, when the sorting function starts to use that address, it will think its indexing into pointers, when the underlying structure is an array of arrays.

Answer (score 1):

A `int **` is a pointer to a pointer to an `int`, and *can be* a pointer to an array of pointers to arrays of `int`s. A `int [][]` is a 2-dimensional array of `int`s. A two-dimensional array is exactly the same as a one-dimensional array in C in one respect: It is fundamentally a pointer to the first object. The only difference is the accessing, a two-dimensional array is accessed with two different strides simultaneously.
Long story short, a `int[][]` is closer to an `int*` than an `int**`.

Comment: So an int[][] is stored continously in the memory just like with an int[] is? The only difference is the indexing? int[i][j] gets translated into int[i*columns + j]? Or is it stored in a column major way?

Comment: @VSZM: Yes to the first and second questions. Not sure how to answer the other questions, that depends on which you see as the row or column. Either way, multidimensional arrays are not a strength of C, and you shouldn't rely on implementation details (people have abused the multiple strides in the past).

Comment: After some experimenting I found out that (with the current compiler gcc  4.8.1) the int[][] array is stored continously in row major order.